# Build a dataset from api response

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this :

```
{
    "2018-12": 1778
    "2018-11": 3190
    "2018-10": 5318
    "2018-09": 2498
    "2018-08": -2791
    "2018-07": 1710
    "2018-06": 1786
    "2019-12": 3513.97
    "2019-11": 2975.9700000000003
    "2019-10": -5407.53
    "2019-09": 5188.02
    "2019-08": 5599.2699999999995
    "2019-07": 3930.37
    "2019-06": 1434.95
    "2019-05": 4834.02
    "2019-04": 2479.5299999999997
    "2019-03": 6247.06
    "2019-02": 2066.4
    "2019-01": 2073.8799999999997
    "2020-12": 1092.79
}
```

My code is :

```
    let data = (new Array(12)).fill(null);
    const datasets = [];
    const colors = ['#4A90E270', '#27AE6070', '#F7981C70', '#47381C70'];
    let colorIndex = 0;
    Object.entries(inputObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const [year, month] = key.split('-');
      const foundElement = datasets.some((el) => el.label === year.toString());
      if (!foundElement) {
        datasets.push({
          data,
          label: year.toString(),
          borderColor: colors[colorIndex],
          fill: false,
          lineTension: 0,
        });
        colorIndex += 1;
        data = (new Array(12)).fill(null);
      }
      data[parseInt(month, 10) - 1] = parseFloat(value).toFixed(1);
    });
```

But is not working as expected. Because I want to get all values by year, for example put all data for year `2018` in `data`, after data reset `data` and put for year `2019` all data. How can I resolve this? Now like is done is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what's your expected result.

If you need to push all your data in a object by year, then you need to iterate your data by keys and then push your value to the year key .

```js
const data = {
    "2018-12": 1778,
    "2018-11": 3190,
    "2018-10": 5318,
    "2018-09": 2498,
    "2018-08": -2791,
    "2018-07": 1710,
    "2018-06": 1786,
    "2019-12": 3513.97,
    "2019-11": 2975.9700000000003,
    "2019-10": -5407.53,
    "2019-09": 5188.02,
    "2019-08": 5599.2699999999995,
    "2019-07": 3930.37,
    "2019-06": 1434.95,
    "2019-05": 4834.02,
    "2019-04": 2479.5299999999997,
    "2019-03": 6247.06,
    "2019-02": 2066.4,
    "2019-01": 2073.8799999999997,
    "2020-12": 1092.79,
}

let result = {}

Object.keys(data).forEach(date => {
   const year = date.split("-")[0]
   if(!result[year]){
     result[year]=[data[date]]
   }
   else{
     result[year].push(data[date])
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but is possible to put directly in my `datasets` ?

Comment: what do you mean ? You can do whatever you want with your result object